# Error whenn installing awsebcli via Gitlab CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, gitlab, gitlab-ci, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have springboot project in gitlab that I try to deploy to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk environment that I created via Amazon web console.

In gitlab I am using Default shared Runners.

to deploy to AWS I must use 'eb' cli, for this I also need python

I tired to use this in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
deploy:
 stage: deploy
 image: python:3.7.2-alpine3.7
 script:  
  - pip install -r awsebcli
  - eb use myenv-env -v
  - eb deploy myenv-env -v
```

But got errors:

```
Pulling docker image python:3.7.2-alpine3.7 ...
Using docker image sha256:00be2573e9f79754b17954ba7a310a5f70c25b6f5bb78375e27e9e86d874877e for python:3.7.2-alpine3.7 ...
Running on runner-0c303413-project-4590-concurrent-0 via ed06f0845ef4...
Fetching changes...
Removing .m2/
Removing target/
HEAD is now at 5c19020 aws1
Checking out 5c190200 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for default...
Successfully extracted cache
Downloading artifacts for build (14719)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=14719 responseStatus=200 OK token=Yy7j2TGy
$ pip install -r awsebcli
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'awsebcli'
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

**Update**

when I changed the line into:

```
pip3 install awsebcli
```

got:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe6611ff2e8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve')': /simple/awsebcli/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement awsebcli (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for awsebcli
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was proxy.

I added this:

pip3 --proxy=myProxy:myPort install awsebcli --upgrade